# Does incidence of appearance of quantum fluctuation particles being lowered due to space expansion?

Tags: space-expansion, virtual-particles

1. in volume of space some amount of virtual particles appears during 1 second
2. amount of matter and energy in universe is constant (pls. correct me if I'm wrong)
3. space (universe) is expanding

**question**: will be the amount of appeared virtual particles during 1 second due to space expansion remain the same in future in same volume?

I understand that it is probably impossible to give an answer on basis of experiment. But what theory say?

Comment: I'm afraid this question doesn't make much sense to me - what does "incidence of appaearce of quantum fluctuation particles" mean, and what has this to do with space expansion?

Comment: @ACuriousMind please red my edit, may be, I'm more clear now

Comment: I think this is clear enough. The questioner is aware that virtual pairs appear in the quantum vacuum state, and wants to know if those virtual pairs occur with less frequency as the universe expands. (As in, are they "stretched out" or "dispersed"? Does the universe feel like butter spread over too much bread?)

Comment: Which is not to say that the question is 100% right in its premises but I think a good answer is possible (not sure I can really write it)

Comment: @zeldredge It is sort of interesting to try to answer this! I would be tempted to say "no", because these "virtual particle pairs" are a heuristic way of explaining vacuum energy, and vacuum energy density is constant.

Comment: @knzhou Does it mean that you would say that in early universe incidence of appearance of VP was higher? Then, also should be a maximum possible number of appearances in volume unit. That also leads to conclusion that in enough dense universe quantum fluctuations are impossible. Am I right?

Comment: I believe this question already has an answer here: [Does the density of virtual particles decrease when space expands due to dark energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207098/does-the-density-of-virtual-particles-decrease-when-space-expands-due-to-dark-en) and there is another very similar question here [Conservation of energy vs expansion of space](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259759/conservation-of-energy-vs-expansion-of-space).