# Does light orbit the universe?

Tags: cosmology, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

Or rather, does mass-less particles orbit the matter in the universe due to the infinite range of gravity? And if yes, in what shape are they orbiting? A ring as on Saturn? Maybe a whirlpool due to the expansion of space? A full shell?

Comment: Just a few points: Gravity is not a force, so it does not have an infinite range, rather it is a manifestation of Spacetime curvature. Second, something orbiting something else in GR is understood as geodesic motion. So you can have null geodesic motion *within* a universe / a solution of Einstein's equations, but I don't know what light orbiting the universe would mean.

Comment: I think the question would be interpreted to ask whether in a cosmological solution there is a lightlike horizon at large or infinite a(t), the scale factor?

Comment: @BobBee Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I illustrate in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257476/how-did-the-universe-shift-from-dark-matter-dominated-to-dark-energy-dominate/257542#257542) how a cosmology with a constant density of energy in the vacuum will in fact accelerate outwards. This will not permit the orbiting of particles or light on a large scale.

There is the Godel solution that has closed timelike curves. This is different than an orbit, but a case where geodesics have a time parameter that is topologically a circle. The anti-de Sitter spacetime is similar in that $AdS_n$ has topology $\mathbb R^{n-1}\times\mathbb S^1$. Here the spatial surface is the $\mathbb R^{n-1}$  and time is $S^1$. This spacetime is different from the spacetime that approximates what we observe that is $\mathbb S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$. However, it is possible that our observable cosmology emerges from and anti-de Sitter spacetime. Maybe the inflationary spacetime that spins off cosmology at a lower vacuum energy is an anti-de Sitter spacetime.

Comment: The late time cosmological spacetime with dark energy dominating and exponentially expanding the universe does indeed have a Killing, or lightlike horizon. The lightlike orbits at that value of r are indeed geodesics. The Killing vector goes from timelike to space like across it. If the question is opened up I can expand.